# Не запускается apk файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

После сборки приложения в .apk на kivy (без KivyMD, собирал через бульдозер) приложение висит в загрузке и вылетает. После включения отладки вывело такую ошибку:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jdcal'

Собирал на специальной виртуальной машине от разработчиков kivy. Приложение из исходников полностью работает.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете sqlite3 и openpyxl ,то у вас должны быть такие зависимости в buildozer.spec:

```
requirements = python3,kivy,openpyxl,sqlite3,jdcal,et_xmlfile
```

Я это выяснил при помощи adb с командой logcat:

```
adb logcat | grep pyth
```

Comment: При этом должен быть включен режим отладки по usb на телефоне